# Pattern Search by User Input -bash

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to write a bash script that will take user input and search my file for matches. And then format the output to new lines

This is what I have but I'm getting an error *unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''*

```
echo 'Enter a Keyword: '
read Keyword
awk -v Keyword="$Keyword" '/$0 ~ Keyword/ -F: '{ print " Name: "$1"\n","Phone: "$2"\n","Email: "$3" }' myfile
```

Comment: Number of `"` is odd. Remove last `"`.

Comment: The single quotes are weird to: You first have a `'/$0 ~ Keyword/ -F: '`, followed by a `{`, then a space, which terminates this argument. Fix your quotes first. Perhaps the error will disappear.